# Cannot connect to MySQL - host not allowed

Tags: mysql

I've just started working with Hibernate and when I'm finally trying to launch the web-app I get the following error:

```
2012-nov-14 12:54:23 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
ERROR: HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.7' is not allowed to
connect to this MySQL server"
```

Which is really frustrating. Why aren't I a localhost? What is 192.168.1.7? I could just grant privileges like the answers to similar questions suggest but why aren't I localhost?

I understand the problem here, the hbm2ddl setting is set to create, so it wants to create the given tables but doesn't get permission from the MySQL-server.

I'm developing a struts2/hibernate app in Eclipse and I use Tomcat and of course MYSQL.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: (hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clothes</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Needs to be disabled in production! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="johanstenberg.clothes.serverobjects.AdEntity"/>
    <mapping class="johanstenberg.clothes.serverobjects.AuthenticationEntity"/>
    <mapping class="johanstenberg.clothes.serverobjects.UserEntity"/>
    <mapping class="johanstenberg.clothes.serverobjects.VerificationKeyEntity"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look into your hibernate configuration file. There is an entry with

> <property name="connection.url"> ... </property>

You must change this entry to connect to mysql at localhost.

Next look into mysql. Connect to mysql and check privileges:

> $ mysql -u root -p
>   mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
>   mysql> show grants for 'root'@'192.168.1.7';

If there are no grants for the appropriate database or tables, add them:

> mysql> grant all privileges on clothes.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

or

> mysql> grant all privileges on clothes.* to 'root'@'192.168.1.7' identified by 'password';

and then

> mysql> flush privileges;

Comment: <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clothes</property> is already localhost as you can see

Comment: Check the Edit in the question-post above, I don't think the error is there though, check it out please!

Comment: @JohanS Everything looks regular, no surprises here. Next step would be to check the mysql configuration.

Comment: I have no grants on 192.168.1.7, but how do I connect as localhost instead of 192.168.1.7?

Comment: Do you have grants for localhost? If yes what is the output?

Comment: I did your instructions and now it works, why I'm 192.168.1.7 and not a localhost will always be a mystery...

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Can't figure out why it thinks im at 68-245-171-115.pools.spcsdns.net... my error is "Cause: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '68-245-171-115.pools.spcsdns.net' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: @Verdagon You must look into the hibernate configuration file. The property `connection.url` tells you, through which interface the client tries to connect to the mysql server.

Answer (score 7):

run this command on your MySQL instance (replace the tokens)

```
CREATE USER '${username}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${password}';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '${username}'@'%';
```

this will allow you to connect to mysql from any host. 192.168.1.7 is the ip of your computer.

If you want to secure your db instance, read the this bit of the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: What do you mean ip of my computer? Ip of my computer in my home network? Is there no way I can connect as localhost instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are severals steps which you need to do:

Step1: do some configuration on my.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Step2: go to mysql command(("your_remote_ip" is the pc which wants to access your mysql))

```
mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_mysql_username'@'your_remote_ip'IDENTIFIED BY 'your_mysql_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Step3: you can check its configuration on mysql

```
use mysql;

select user, host from user;
```

Step4: restart your mysql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```